# javascript (nodejs) while loop bug

Tags: javascript, node.js

running the following code in nodejs cli:

```
var my_function = function() {                                                                                              
    var next_value = 1
      , value = undefined
      , difference = undefined                                                                                              
      , prev_difference = undefined                                                                                         

    while ((typeof prev_difference === 'undefined') || (prev_difference > 0)) {                               
        value = next_value 
        next_value = 2
        difference = next_value - value 
        if (difference > prev_difference) {                                                                                 
              throw new Error('Diminishing')
        }                                                                                                                   
        prev_difference = 0 
    }                                                                                                                       
    return next_value 
}              

for (var i = 0; i< 300; i++) { console.log(i); console.log(my_function()) }
```

At iteration 282 of the loop I start getting the value '1' instead of '2'. Can't for the life of me understand why. This chunk of code is a reduction from something else I've been working on, hence the seemingly unnecessary if statement within the loop. There are a few ways to change this code such that the execution path does not get screwed up, but I'd like to understand why it's breaking with the current setup.

Also, if you have any tips for tools that could aid me in debugging something like this in the future I would be very grateful. For the most part I used console.log to narrow this down.

node.js version v0.8.6. Running on Mac OSX version 10.7.5. 
Thanks

Comment: This seems like a Node bug to me; the behavior is really strange. (I can duplicated it too.) *edit* I guess it may be a V8 bug and not a Node bug ...

Comment: Don't think it's V8 because Chrome doesn't seem to have the same problem... ?

Comment: I'm running Node 0.8.6 on Linux (32-bit), and I don't show that behavior.

Comment: Node v0.8.14 (Ubuntu 64bit) also see this bug. I think it need to be reported here https://github.com/joyent/node/issues?direction=desc&page=1&sort=created&state=open

Comment: @VadimBaryshev: Do you see the bug in Chrome?

Comment: I can also confirm that I see the behavior on Node 0.8.11, OSX. But I do not see the bug in Chrome 22, OSX.

Comment: @user1689607: no, in Chrome everything is OK. (Chrome 22, Windows 7 64bit).

Comment: Just posted this bug here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4236

Comment: also works fine with node.js on Win7. Could be some memory corruption issue due to throwing too many errors.

Comment: @mihai It's not throwing *any* errors. My guess is that it has something to do with optimization - that would explain why it changes after a certain number of iterations.

Comment: @Pointy ah..you're right, that line doesn't get executed. Oh well...another weird bug

Comment: @Pointy that was my original thought as well, but it's strange that it would optimize the while condition to false. If any thing I thought it would get optimized to always be true.

Comment: @user1797466 well "strange" is kind-of what you get from bugs :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you take out the IF statement it is gonna be fine, it will return only '2' on every iteration. The variable prev_difference is 'undefined' every time and this seems to cause issues.

Comment: Yes, we have been able to figure that out. The question is *why*? Because it shouldn't. It's perfectly valid to work with undefined variables in JavaScript.