# nodejs freezes when attempting to purposely block the event loop?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Besides this post [javascript (nodejs) while loop bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215822/javascript-nodejs-while-loop-bug)
which is a different issue with the "while" loop in node js, I can't seem to understand why the following code doesn't 'block.'  I am trying to get the event loop to block so that I can block requests (this is just for testing/pleasure and getting familiar with nodejs).

```
http = require('http')

data = ""
processData = (chunk) ->
    date = new Date()
    dm = date.getMilliseconds()
    curDate = null
    loop
        curDate = (new Date()).getMilliseconds()
        break if curDate-dm > 4000
    data += chunk


endData = ->
    console.log(data)
    data = ""

requestListener = (req,res) ->
    req.on "data", processData
    req.on "end", endData
    res.writeHead 200
    res.write "hello buddy"
    res.end()

webserver = http.createServer requestListener
webserver.listen(6666)
```

I am expecting some sort of blocking for 4 seconds, and then console displaying some data from the request via

```
curl -d "testdata=32" "http://localhost:6666"
```

however, node never writes anything to the console nor sends a response back to client and just 'freezes.'  If i increase the time to 100 milliseconds it works for the first 5-8 tries (sends data back to curl) but eventually freezes.   Am I missing something here?  is this a bug? Shouldn't node handle this gracefully?

I have encountered other methods for blocking that do work such as:

```
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + 4000);
```

My env: windows 7/cywin 2.774/nodejs 0.8.10/ curl 7.27.0

Comment: Your issue stems from the use of [`Date.prototype.getMilliseconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) -- this is the milliseconds part of the current time, not the current time in milliseconds, which is instead [`Date.prototype.getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). That's also why it (sometimes) works with a smaller difference.

Comment: @LinusGThiel: You should make that an answer. :)